# Looking for a value of an NSDictionary in another NSDictionary to make "required" UITableView groups

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a grouped UITableview which I populate with a JSON object. Some of the sections/groups is required to have at least one row checked. With each tap, I add a key/value to an NSMutableDictionary to construct my selected array. Now on a IBAction I need to check if every "required" group has something selected. I know which of the sections are required from my json  object that indicates it.

My thought is to get all IDs from my new array and see if each "required" group has at least one key in the "master" NSDictionary, although I don't know if it's the right thought

A little schematic to help:

"Master" json object in an nsdictionary

```
  {
        "category_id": "2",
        "category_required": "1",
        "category_items": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "categoryid": "2",
                "title": "Pie",
                "price": "1.20",
                "offer_price": null,
                "can_have_multi": "0"
            },
            {
                "id": "2",
                "categoryid": "2",
                "title": "Tea",
                "price": "1.50",
                "offer_price": null,
                "can_have_multi": "0"
            },
```

etc...

"selected items" nsdictionary:

```
"ingredients" : {
    "8" : {
      "multi" : "1"
    },
    "13" : {
      "multi" : "1"
    },
    "12" : {
      "multi" : "1"
    },
    "2" : {
      "multi" : "1"
    }
  },
```

etc...

So, the idea is to compare each of the second array's ids to the master nsdictionary ids after checking which "categories" have required selections.

Does it make sense? Any tips that would help getting me on track would greatly help

Answer (score 0):

I would probably map the data to objects that provide a simpler way to validate it.

#### Object mappings...

```
@interface Category : NSObject
@property (strong) NSString *categoryID;
@property BOOL *selected;    
// Etc... all the category properties
@end

@interface CategoryGroup : NSObject
@property (strong) NSString *group_id;
@property (strong) NSNumber *items_required;
@property (strong) NSArray *categories;    
- (BOOL)enoughCategoriesSelected
@end

@implementation CategoryGroup

- (BOOL)enoughCategoriesSelected
{
  NSInteger selected = 0;
  for (Category *cat in self.categories)
  {
    if (cat.selected)
      selected++;
  }
  return (selected >= self.items_required.intValue);
}
@end
```

#### Tableview stuff...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // .....
  CategoryGroup *group = self.groups[indexPath.section];
  Category *cat = group.categories[indexPath.row];

  if (cat.selected)
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
  else
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
  // ....
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  // ...
  CategoryGroup *group = self.groups[indexPath.section];
  Category *cat = group.categories[indexPath.row];
  cat.selected = !cat.selected;
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

#### Finally...

```
- (IBAction)validateCategoryGroups
{  
  for (CategoryGroup *group in self.groups)
  {
    if ([group enoughCategoriesSelected])
      // all good...
    else
      // no good...
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a very elegant solution. Although, I have no experience with objects and I have so many references to my arrays in my project to change everything. Thanks a lot for your reply, I will consider studying it further to make use of this approach on my next project.

For now, I have used a 'dirty' but in a few lines only solution: I iterate through an array with the required categories and see if any of their products is in my 'selected' array. If I find a match, the requirement is met. I count this per category in order to fulfill all required categories/groups.

Comment: Look into [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/index.html) for converting your JSON data back and forth between objc models